# How to disable translation for a specific symfony route?

Tags: php, internationalization, symfony

I am working on a internationalized symfony app where the locale for a webpage is in the url (eg : `/en/myaccount` and `/fr/moncompte`).

What I would like to have is a custom webpage where I can see the page not translated, with he translation keys. This behaviour should not change the behavior for the localized pages.

I have tried to add a locale with no translation file. However the website fallback to the default locale which prevents seeing translation keys. Is there a way to disable localization (or fallback for a specific locale ? Is it possible to use a custom url which is not associated with a locale in the routing ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the route with options={"i18n":"false"}
then in the path you make locale like extensions you get something like this

```
/**
 *@Route("/{prefix}/moncompte", methods={"GET"}, options={"i18n":"false"}, requirements={"prefix"="fr|en|ar"})
*/
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, use an else when routing fail ("not found route") then include this page instead of redirect to 404 page.